# Why is an lowpass filter applied to an AKAppleSampler when starting / stopping Audiokit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, audiokit

I am having an issue when using the AKAppleSampler and starting and stopping the audioKit. Everytime its stopped and started a lowpassfilter is applied.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var sampler: AKAppleSampler? = nil

    @IBAction func onButtonSetup(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            self.sampler = AKAppleSampler()
            if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "piano", withExtension: "aupreset") {
                let presetPath: String = url.path
                try sampler?.loadPath(presetPath)
                AudioKit.output = sampler
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onStop(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try AudioKit.stop()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onStart(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onPlay(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try sampler?.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the repro-repo

https://github.com/mlostekk/AudioKitIssue

To reproduce it do the following

1. Press Setup
2. Press Audiokit start
3. Press Play (sounds normal)
4. Press AudioKit stop
5. Press AudioKit start
6. Press Play (lowpassfilter gets applied a bit)
7. Now repeat 4, 5 and 6 and see that the LP filter is applied more with each start stop cycle

Any solution to this?